# How to get mkbootimg for Android kernel development for Sony Xperia ZR?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, android-source, sony

I recently got the kernel to compile under Ubuntu (see [my answer on Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/412405/181442) for details) but noted that the `~/10.4.B.0.569/kernel/README_Xperia` file mentions some prerequisites such as

```
* ramdisk.img - root fs
* mkbootimg - boot.img generator
```

to be required as well. And while I have seen some guides about how to create the `ramdisk.img`, I haven't found how to obtain the `mkbootimg` for the Sony Xperia ZR kernel.

Any pointers are appreciated, thank you!

**EDIT**

Here is a somewhat old (2011) [Sony tutorial on how to build kernels](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/05/06/how-to-build-a-linux-kernel/), unfortunately this also doesn't explain how to get `ramdisk.img`. For `mkbootimg`, it says:

> Now that we have all the parts we need to create a flashable file. The
>   next stop is to package the parts. To do this, you’ll need the program
>   mkbootimg, which is part of the standard Android tree. If you don’t feel 
>   like compiling all of Android to get this tool, it is available to 
>   download from various trusted sites on the Internet.

Apart from not having found any "official" (such as Sony or Android/Google which is what I would call "trusted" in this context) sites to download `mkbootimg` from, it sounds like it *should* be possible to build (?) `mkbootimg` from the "standard Android tree". Anyone know how to do that?

Similar information can also be found [here, with more recent Sony tutorial](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/02/21/update-on-xperia-open-source-archives/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=update-on-xperia-open-source-archives), about `mkbootimg` and `ramdisk.img`:

> *How to obtain these files is beyond the scope of this document, but note that they should match the phone model and the rest of the
>   software.

Now if `mkbootimg` can be built from standard Android sources, how would this "match the phone model"?

**EDIT 2**

This thread on the XDA Forums might also be helpful in finding an answer: [[Tutorial] Kernel building instructions for Xperia devices](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2447310), which has a [section for Xperia Z, ZL, ZR, Tablet Z](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=45653382#post45653382) devices.

Answer (score 3):

I found the source code for mkbootimg / mkbootfs

`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core.git`

I found these compilation instructions to work:

https://gist.github.com/jberkel/1087757